# Delete duplicate rows from SELECT query?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I'm working with SQLite and currently attempting to delete certain duplicate rows from a certain user (with ID 12345). I've managed to identify all of the rows I wish to delete, but I'm now unsure how to go about deleting these rows. This is my `SELECT` query:

```
SELECT t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by code, version) 
as cnt from t) t
where cnt >= 2 and userID = "12345";
```

How would I go about deleting the rows matching this result? Can I use the query above in some way to identify which rows I want to delete? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the duplicate `code, version` combinations for `userid = '12345'` with this query:

```
select code, version
from tablename
where userid = '12345'
group by code, version
having count(*) > 1
```

and you can use it in the `DELETE` statement:

```
delete from tablename 
where userid = '12345'
and (code, version) in (
  select code, version
  from tablename
  where userid = tablename.userid
  group by code, version
  having count(*) > 1
)
```

If you want to keep 1 of the duplicate rows, use `MIN()` window function to get the row with the min `rowid` for each combination of `code, version` and exclude it from being deleted:

```
delete from tablename 
where userid = '12345'
and rowid not in (
  select distinct min(rowid) over (partition by code, version)
  from tablename
  where userid = tablename.userid
)
```

Comment: I see. Would it be possible to only delete one of the duplicate rows if the user 12345 has 2 rows with the same value?

Comment: Can this work if one of the duplicate rows is "owned" by another user than 12345? Or must both rows be "owned" by 12345?

Comment: I understand. What would I need to modify in order to have it working with rows "owned" by both 12345 and another user? Only deleting the row owned by 12345.

Comment: This is a different requirement for which you should post a new question where you must explain what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . you don't have to use window functions:

```
delete from t
    where exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.code = t.code and t2.version = t.version
                  group by code, version
                  having count(*) >= 2
                 );
```

Comment: What is ```t2``` in this case?

Comment: @Californium . . . It is a table alias for the reference to your (unnamed) table in the subquery.  I note that this answer was 12 minutes earlier than the other answer.