# Delete duplicate rows with different user IDs in SQL?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, sql-delete

I recently asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64721250/delete-duplicate-rows-from-select-query) question about how I could delete all duplicate rows if the duplicate rows were all under one user ID. Now I'm wondering what I should do in terms of removing one duplicate row if the rows with duplicate values have different user IDs?

For example, if I have:

```
+--------+----+---------+
| UserID | ID | Version |
+--------+----+---------+
|      1 | AB |       1 |
|      2 | AB |       1 |
|      1 | BA |       1 |
|      2 | BA |       1 |
+--------+----+---------+
```

The values in `ID` and `Version` are identical (for AB and BA rows respectively), and I would like to only delete the rows that have the UserID of 1 (deleting the first and third row). How would I go about doing this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

*Delete* a row from the table when a row with same ID and same Version *exists*, but with a higher UserID.

```
delete from tablename t1
where exists (select 1 from tablename t2
              where t1.ID = t2.ID and t1.Version = t2.Version
                and t1.UserID < t2.UserID)
```

Comment: Is it possible to make the query more specific, targeting the user with ID 1 (in case one user has a higher ID exists)?